# How to convert date from react calendar in the dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-calendar

I am using `react-calendar` , Here I am getting a date in the following format

```
Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Now I am trying to convert it to `dd/mm/yyyy`. is there any way though which I can do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The native Date object comes with seven formatting methods. Each of these seven methods give you a specific value -

- `toString()` : Fri Jul 02 2021 14:03:54 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
- `toDateString()`: Fri Jul 02 2021
- `toLocaleString()` : 7/2/2021, 2:05:07 PM
- `toLocaleDateString()` : 7/2/2021
- `toGMTString()` : Fri, 02 Jul 2021 13:06:02 GMT
- `toUTCString()` : Fri, 02 Jul 2021 13:06:28 GMT
- `toISOString()` : 2021-07-02T13:06:53.422Z

```js
var date = new Date();

// toString()
console.log(date.toString());

// toDateString()
console.log(date.toDateString());

// toLocalString()
console.log(date.toLocaleString());

// toLocalDateString()
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());

// toGMTString()
console.log(date.toGMTString());

// toGMTString()
console.log(date.toUTCString());

// toGMTString()
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Format Indian Standard time to Local time -

```js
const IndianDate = 'Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';

const localDate = new Date(IndianDate).toLocaleDateString();

console.log(localDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the methods shown in this blogpost https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-format-date-dd-mm-yyyy from Borislav Hadzhiev.

You could a new date based on your calendar date and afterwards format it:

```
function padTo2Digits(num) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

function formatDate(date) {
  return [
    padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),
    padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1),
    date.getFullYear(),
  ].join('/');
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date('Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)')));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JavaScript default date format.

You can use libraries like momentjs, datefns, etc to get the result.

For example, if you are using momentjs:-

moment(date).format('dd/mm/yyyy);

Or if you don't want to use any third-party library you can get the result from  JavaScript's default date object methods.

const date = new Date();

const day = date.getDate() < 10 ? `0${date.getDate()}` : date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? `0${date.getMonth() + 1}` : date.getDate() + 1;
const year = date.getFullYear();

const formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;